# The type or namespace name 'ASP' could not be found

Tags: c#, asp.net, sharepoint

I have recently been tasked with upgrading an existing Visual Studio 2005 / SharePoint 2007 web part to work with Visual Studio 2015 / SharePoint 2013.

The original solution used a deployment project (which is no longer supported in 2015) to create a webpart containing a user control (ascx) and its supporting files, which were deployed in a single DLL.

The problem I have is in the webpart source file that contains a reference to the user control:

```
protected override System.Web.UI.Control GetApplicationControl()
{
    return new ASP.transcriptlandingview_ascx();
}
```

Which generates the error:

> The type or namespace name ‘ASP’ could not be found (are you missing a
>   using directive or assembly reference?)

The namespace ASP appears to be associated with the deployment project, but I have not been able to find any documentation about this.

Is there an equivalent of the ASP namespace for the Visual Studio 2015 Publishing  tool? Or a better way of referencing the control?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although deployment projects are no longer supported, the Publish wizard does still contain the functionality to deploy to a single DLL. In Solution Explorer, right-click the project and select "Publish..." to start the wizard.

On the **Connections** page, set the **Publish method** to **File System** and enter the target path.

On the **Settings** page, from **File Publish Options** select **Precompile during publishing** then click on the **Configure** link

[Publish Wizard - Settings page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Cj3W.png)

[Publish Wizard - Configuration Page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cogW6.png)

Select **Merge all outputs to a single assembly** and enter the name of the deployment URL.

Publish the project. Add a reference to the deployment URL to the Webpart project, and Hey Presto, you have access to the ASP namespace!

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you create a new web part for SharePoint 2013, then migrate the logic code from the old web part to the new web part.

[How to: Create a SharePoint web part](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/sharepoint/how-to-create-a-sharepoint-web-part)

[3 Simple Steps to Create a Visual Web Part in SharePoint](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1020663/Simple-Steps-to-Create-a-Visual-Web-Part-in-ShareP)

Comment: Thanks for that. Reluctantly coming to the same conclusion myself.